# string splitter in C - how is it working?

Tags: c, split, substring, c-strings, function-definition

I have inherited a large code base and there is a utility function to split strings on `:` char. I understand about 80% of how it works, I do not understand the `*token = '\0';` line.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_TOKEN_SIZE 200

const char *splitter(const char *str, char delimiter, char *token) {

    while (*str && (delimiter != *str)) {
        *token++ = *str;
        str++;            
    }
    if (delimiter == *str)
        str++;

    *token = '\0';    // what is this line doing?

    //how could the token be correct in the main() after setting it to null terminator 
    //here?

    return str;
} 

int main() {
    char token[MAX_TOKEN_SIZE + 1];  
    const char *env = "/bin:/sbin:::/usr/bin";
    while (*env) {
        env = splitter(env, ':', token);  

        //if token is empty, set it to "./"
        if ((token != NULL) && (token[0] == '\0')) {
            strcpy(token, "./\0");            
        }

        printf("%s\n", token)  ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is correct:

```
/bin
/sbin
./
./
/usr/bin
```

Comment: You're copying `char`acters from `str` to `token` and `\0` (NUL) terminating it so you can use `<string.h>` functions and `printf`.

Comment: @Yoshiro This if statement if ((token != NULL) && (token[0] == '\0')) { has a redundant expression. It may be written like if ( token[0] == '\0') {

Comment: Thanks Vlad from Moscow. I will take your suggestion and modify the code. I will appreciate if you could point out any other inefficiencies in the code. Thank you.

Comment: Note that if `token` is actually a `char *` instead of a `char []`, the `NULL` check makes sense again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are subtle problems in the posted code:

- the test `if ((token != NULL) && (token[0] == '\0'))` is redundant: `token` is an array, hence `token!= NULL` is always true.
- `splitter` does not receive the length of the destination array: if the `str` argument contains a token longer than `MAX_TOKEN_SIZE` bytes, it will cause undefined behavior because of a buffer overflow.
- if the `delimiter` passed to `splitter` is the null byte, the return value will point beyond the end of the string, potentially causing undefined behavior.
- the line `*token = '\0';` just sets the null terminator at the end of the token copied from `str`, if any.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_TOKEN_SIZE 200

const char *splitter(const char *str, char delimiter, char *token, size_t size) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while (*str) {
        char c = *str++;
        if (c == delimiter)
            break;
        if (i + 1 < size)
            token[i++] = c;
    }
    if (i < size) {
        token[i] = '\0';  /* set the null terminator */
    }
    return str;
} 

int main() {
    char token[MAX_TOKEN_SIZE + 1];  
    const char *env = "/bin:/sbin:::/usr/bin";
    while (*env) {
        env = splitter(env, ':', token, MAX_TOKEN_SIZE + 1);  

        // if token is empty, set it to "./"
        if (*token == '\0') {
            strcpy(token, "./");            
        }
        printf("%s\n", token);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters I will point to a redundant code.

This if statement

```
if ((token != NULL) && (token[0] == '\0')) {
```

has a senseless expression because `token` never can be equal to `NULL`. `token` in main is declared as a character array. So you could write

```
if ( token[0] == '\0') {
```

Also in the string literal in this statement

```
strcpy(token, "./\0");
```

the explicit terminating zero character `'\0'` is redundant. You can just write

```
strcpy(token, "./");
```

As for your question.

The function `splitter` extracts a sequence of characters until the character `delimiter` is encountered and stores it in the array `token`,

```
while (*str && (delimiter != *str)){
     *token++ = *str;
     str++;            
}
```

But the result sequence does not represent a string. It shall be ended with the terminating zero character `\0` and this statement

```
*token = '\0';
```

appends the terminating zero character to the end of the extracted sequence stored in the array `token`.

As for this statement

```
if (delimiter == *str)
    str++;
```

then if it is not the end of the string `str` (that is if the current character `*str` is not the terminating zero character '\0'; if it is equal to `delimiter` then it is not the terminating zero character) then the pointer `str` is incremented and returned from the function to allow the caller in the next call of the function continue to process the string from the next positions.

So initially you have

```
 const char *env = "/bin:/sbin:::/usr/bin";
```

the function copies character `/bin` appended with the zero character `'\0'` that is the string "/bin" to the array token. After this call the returned pointer from the function will point to the substring

```
"/sbin:::/usr/bin"
```

because the preceding character `':'` was skipped by this statement

```
if (delimiter == *str)
    str++;
```

within the function.

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated, the line in question is setting the `char` pointed to by `token` to the `nul` terminator (as is required by virtually all string-handling functions in C).

But, assuming there are other characters in the extracted token, those will already have been added, sequentially, to the target array by the earlier `*token++ = *str;` line. Note that this copies a character to the pointed-to element of the array **and then increments the pointer** (so that it then points to the *next* `char` in the string/array).

So, when the `while` loop has finished, `token` will be pointing to the element of the array that immediately follows the last character copied in that loop – which is exactly where there needs to be a `nul` terminator.

Comment: Thank you Adrian Mole. Now I understand, we are relying on the postfix increment operator to arrive at the correct position for null terminator. I have another question if you do not mind : how is token in the main() getting reset for the next iteration of while loop? I do not see anything setting it to null after we get the token from splitter. Thank you again.

Comment: @Yoshiro In your `main` function, the call to `splitter` uses the *same* `token` array each time through the loop. That will always 'decay' to a pointer to the first element of the array, so the function will always start there (and overwrite any characters put there by a previous call).

Comment: `token` is not *reset* in the `main` function, the next call to `splitter()` copies the next token into the array and sets a null byte at the end. If no more tokens are present, the destination array will contain an empty string.

Comment: Thank you all of you, I have learned so much. Wish I could Accept all of your comments. Thanks again.